# RSA Encryption on Flutter and Decryption in Python

Tags: python, flutter, dart, encryption, rsa

I am currently working on my first Flutter project and I would like to explain the situation first:

1. I am writing a Python Api using Flask which creates an RSA key pair as follows and stores them into files:

   ```
    def generate_rsa_key_pair(self):
    key = RSA.generate(2048)
    private_key = key.export_key()
    file_out = open("private.pem", "wb")
    file_out.write(private_key)
    file_out.close()

    public_key = key.publickey().export_key()
    file_out = open("public.pem", "wb")
    file_out.write(public_key)
    file_out.close()
   ```
2. The client, my Flutter app, now requests the public key to encrypt its messages with. This public key is then transmitted as follows:

   ```
    public_key = RSA.import_key(open("public.pem").read())
    keys["publicKey"] = public_key.exportKey("PEM").decode("utf-8")
   ```

   The public key that is stored in the file is also the same as the one in my       Flutter app. I have already been able to verify this.
3. Now I want to encrypt a message in Flutter using RSA as follows. The public key is stored in the variable *publicEncryptionKey*:

   ```
    import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart' as enc;

    String asymmetricEncrypt(String message) {

      enc.Encrypter encrypter = enc.Encrypter(enc.RSA(publicKey: publicEncryptionKey,  encoding: enc.RSAEncoding.OAEP));

      enc.Encrypted msg = encrypter.encrypt(message);

      return msg.base64;
    }
   ```
4. I send the encrypted message back to my backend and now want to decrypt it with the private key. I do this as follows:

   ```
    from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
    @app.route('/add-element-enc', methods=['POST'])
    def add_element_enc():

       values = request.get_json()

       if 'message' not in values:
          return "", 400

       value1 = values['message']

       private_key = RSA.import_key(open("private.pem", "rb").read())
       decrypter = PKCS1_OAEP.new(private_key)
       new_value = bytes(value1, 'utf-8')
       msg = decrypter.decrypt(new_value)
       return "", 201
   ```

My problem now is that decrypting does not work on my python backend and I get the following error when I try to decrypt the message:

```
ValueError: Ciphertext with incorrect length.
```

I'm getting worn out because I can't get it done. Is there anyone who already had a similar problem?

Comment: In Python you're using `PKCS1_OAEP` cipher. In Dart, you use `RSAEncoding.OAEP`, but [Dart also has](https://pub.dev/documentation/encrypt/latest/encrypt/RSAEncoding.html) `RSAEncoding.PKCS`... have you tried using that instead?

Comment: If you just can't get it to work, you could write the server in Dart and use the exact same settings if using Python is not a strict requirement! Using one language for everything has a lot of advantages :) but yeah, I know it's not always up to you and it may bring other problems...

Comment: Am I just stupid? Because I already looked if I can write my backend in Dart but did not find anything...could you please comment a helpfull link?

Comment: But yes, I already tried the other encodign

Comment: In `add_element_enc()` the Base64 decoding of the ciphertext is missing (instead of the Utf-8 encoding). Furthermore `msg` is not returned.

Comment: You didn't find anything about writing HTTP servers in Dart?? There's info on that even on the standard Dart docs: https://dart.dev/tutorials/server/httpserver and even several frameworks... there's https://github.com/rknell/alfred , https://www.theconduit.dev/ etc.

Comment: Nice thank you. Yeah I found shelf but it was not very comfortable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Topaco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9014097/topaco) wrote in his comment, the solution is that I forgot to base64-decode the message when I receive it.

Kind regards,
Bagheera